# Using innerJoin() in TableSort

Tags: 7

In the examples modules I see a simple example of tableSort with one table.
Searching online I find a post where they claim Drupal 7 allowed a db_select() object to be created and then extended it with a join(), and then the final ->extend('TableSort');

https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/module-development-and-code-questions/2011-12-15/dbtng-tablesort-with-joins-any

I need to do an innerJoin() which appears to be a method of the SelectQuery class, and not necessarily a method of the Tablesort class. That's why the docs I see about extenders say it's critical to invoke the TableSort in the instantiation of the db_select object. Thus, my attempt:

```
$get_all_members = db_select('users', 'u')->innerJoin('members', 'm', 'u.uid = m.uid')->extend('TableSort');
```

> Call to a member function extend() on string

is the response. Is there a way to convert a db_query into a TableSort object like it appears the extender is doing?

Or, could I find a way to combine the fields I need in these two tables to pass to the TableSort object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [issue is addressed](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/module-development-and-code-questions/2011-12-15/dbtng-tablesort-with-joins-any#comment-6029210) in the thread you referenced. Not all methods for the select class return the new query object. In particular, [`innerJoin()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21select.inc/function/SelectQuery%3A%3AinnerJoin/7.x) returns an alias string, not the query object.

Assign your query object so you can reference it outside of the method being called:

```
$query = db_select('users', 'u')->extend('TableSort')
$query->innerJoin('members', 'm', 'u.uid = m.uid');
//@TODO: add ->fields() ->execute() etc...
```